# Spring Boot - backend update without restarting the application

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, backend, updates

Is there a way to update changes (backend) automatically on the website without restarting the application? I'm doing my first project in Spring Boot, some things are not working and to check if the problem was fixed I need to restart the application everytime I change the code.

Comment: What you are looking for is called "hot swapping": https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.running-your-application.hot-swapping, _and_ `LiveReload` in Spring Boot: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.devtools.livereload.

Comment: Perfect - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in Inellij, adding spring-boot-devtools dependency is not enough. You also need to change the settings. Go to File->settings->Build, execution, deployment->Compiler and check Build project automatically
then go to Anvanced Settings and check Allow auto-make to start even if developed application is currently running